# Riemannian gradient in the case of an embedded manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, riemannian-geometry

I am reading a paper regarding optimization on matrix manifolds. In this paper, they state that "The Riemannian gradient in the case of an embedded manifold" is simply the projection on the tangent space of the Euclidean gradient $grad \ f$". I would like to know if this is stated as a proposition/theorem somewhere. In this case our embedded manifold is $O(n)$.

Comment: This is a simple calculation. Try using the inclusion $i : N \to M$ along with the definition of the gradient $df(v) = g(v, grad(f)) $, remembering that $i^{*} df = d i^{*} f$

Comment: I believe this is true for any submanifold of any Riemannian manifold, not just euclidean space. Check out Introduction to Riemannian manifolds by Jack Lee, chapter "Riemannian submanifolds".

Comment: @SpencerKraisler, it is indeed. Can also be found in Riemannian Optimization and its applications by Hiroyuki Sato as Proposition 3.3